# How to extend @Entity and @OneToMany, etc behavior in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

How is possible to extend the @Entity annotation in Spring, lets say to @SpecialEntity to give it addictional methods (ex. int calculateTotalFieldLenght() and fields?
The same question is for other JPA annotations as @OneToMany @Id @etc

Comment: The annotation itself is just a stamp. The functionality is in code that checks for the annotation and then does things based on it.

Comment: Define "extend".

Comment: Exactly Kayaman. But how to do it? Any example?

Comment: Extend: I want that data structure to be modified before inserting. I need to put different behaviors (ex. given get previous record hash) to allow save in blockchain

Comment: Jpa has prepersist event handlers

Answer (score -2):

Add following dependency for your project

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please make sure you understand the question before you try to answer it.